# Total number of illegal states in Tower of Hanoi

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have found that there are 27 (3^n) legal states in the 3-disk, 3-peg puzzle. 
I was wondering if there's a way to calculate the number of illegal configurations or the amount of all possible configurations (and then deduct the legal ones).

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by ilegal states?

Comment: a state where a disk is placed upon a smaller disk

Comment: Try using a combination tree, there can be 1 disk on each peg, 2 on the first and 1 on the second or third, and so on, in each of this states there are 6 configurations, then sum all of them. I can not find an easier way right now.

Answer (score 4):

In the general case, with $n$ disks and $k$ posts, there are $$n!\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$$ possible positions.  To see this note that we can create all positions but arranging the disks in a line in one of $n!$ ways, then splitting the row into $k$ groups and placing the disks in each group on the corresponding peg, in the order they lie in the row.  There are $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ ways to do this, by stars and bars.  Since there are $k^n$ legal positions, the number of illegal positions is $$n!\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}-k^n$$

When $n=k=3$ this gives $33$.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the total number of states, we consider cases on how many discs there are in one stack.

If there are three discs in one stack, there are five ways to stack them illegally, and three places for the stack to go, leading to $15$ illegal positions.

If there are two discs in one stack and one in another, there are three ways to choose two discs, exactly one order to make them illegal, and then six ways to choose how to place the stack of size one and the stack of size two, leading to $18$ illegal positions.

If there are three stacks of one disc each then the position is legal.

So there are $33$ illegal positions.